# gRPC design guidance for turn-based game server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, grpc, .net-5

Anyone have some decent experience with gRPC?  I've got a risk game running right now where all the players are bots with different algorithms that determine how/where they place their armies, and how/where they attack.  I've got a REST implementation right now, where both client and server have to be running an HTTP server; so the client posts to the server to join the game and includes a callback address so the server can post to the client when it's their turn.  That's all working now but it's kind of complex to develop a new client (because they need to host their own http server), plus firewalls make it necessary for all players to be on the same network.

I'm wondering if I were to re-write the client/server interaction logic using gRPC if that wouldn't lend itself toward a more simple design. Using bi-directional streaming the client could call the server asking to join the game, then the client would wait listening to that stream while the rest of the players join the game, and the server could just send a message on that bi-directional stream to the client when it's their turn.  Would that work?

Because pretty much the entire game would be going through that one bi-directional stream, I imagine I'd need to have my message type be flexible enough to account for the different game states.  For example, the Request could contain

- Action {Join/Deploy/Attack}
- ClientName : string
- DeployLocation : string, coordinate of where to place their army
- AttackFrom : string, coordinate
- AttackTo : string, coordinate

Then the response could contain

- GameState {Joining/Deploying/Attacking/GameOver}
- Action {Wait/Deploy/Attack/GameOver}
- Board {list of territories, who occupies them w/how many armies}

In this way, the client would start off by sending a request with only the Action and ClientName filled in.  Then the server would respond with {"GameState": "Joining", "Action": "Wait"}.  Once all the players have joined the game the server would send the first player {"GameState": "Deploying", "Action": "Deploy", "Board": <>} to which the client would send {"DeployLocation": "(1,5)"}.  Then the server asks the next player where they want to deploy an army, etc.

Would that pattern of interaction work?  Is that the wrong way to model the client/server communication in a turn-based game using gRPC?  What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to edit my answer. You are looking for guidance for a potential rewrite of your games server/client to move away from RESTApI. I would highly recommend that you use Signal R Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0
Signal R is specifically designed for a messaged based system. Where you can send a message from your client i.e. "player 1 played card X" and in turn the server will broadcast that message to the other clients that are connected. You can also setup 'groups' which can be used a "lobbies" or "rooms"